# how to write the object in a text file using only javascript? is there any browser compatibilty issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

```
<script>
function select(image)
{
  var str1;
  //.....
  str1 = newURL;
  var fso = ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var abcd = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\\Desktop\\testfile.txt", true);
  abcd.WriteLine(str1);
  abcd.close();
}
</script>
<img  id= "img1" src="abc.png" alt="" onclick="select(this)"  />
```

i am writing this script code in my view.cshtml page. I dont know whats wrong with this code. i want this function to be execute  when i select an image. is there any Assembly refernce to be added here or something?   if there is browser compatibilty issue ?  I have also istalled ActiveX plugin for chrome  but its still not working ? so can any one suggest a better solution for this please?
?

Comment: Have you tried `var fso = new ActiveXObject("Script.FileSystemObject");`? And what exactly isn't working? Do you see an error in the console?

Comment: @MikeC  var fso = new ActiveXObject("Script.FileSystemObject"); is also not  working.I want a textfile to be created at this location on selecting an image  but it is not creating any file there. and  it is not showing any error.